# Combining some of the rows and sum them up in oracle sql

Tags: sql, string, oracle, group-by, sum

I`m working on some data manipulation and have table:

[image: Source Table]

```
Customer  Account   AMT   Charge_1  Charge_2 Charge_3
AB           E      C      a            g      m
AB           E      C      b            h      n
AB           E      C      c            i      o
AB           B      W      d            j      p
AB           B      W      e            k      q
AB           R      V      f            l      r
```

I need to have and output to look like:

```
Customer  Account   AMT   Charge_1  Charge_2  Charge_3
AB           E       C     a+b+c     g+h+i     m+n+o
AB           B       W       d+e       j+k       p+q
AB           R       V         f         l         r
```

[image]

Please suggest what can I use to combine and sum up those.
I appreciate any input!

Thank you

Comment: Please see actual Source and desired  tables- they are linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation. Values are strings, so you probably want to concatenate them rather than sum them (which makes no sense in string context):

```
select
    customer,
    account
    listagg(charge_1, '+') charge_1,
    listagg(charge_2, '+') charge_2,
    listagg(charge_3, '+') charge_3
from mytable
group by customer, account
```

You can control the ordering of the results in the concatenated strings with the `within group` clause:

```
select
    customer,
    account
    listagg(charge_1, '+') within group(order by charge_1) charge_1,
    listagg(charge_2, '+') within group(order by charge_2) charge_2,
    listagg(charge_3, '+') within group(order by charge_3) charge_3
from mytable
group by customer, account
```